# Combining multiple excel file into one workbook with specific row to copy

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple workbooks and I need to combine all of then into one worksheet on a new workbook.

I need only to copy the first row and the last row that say "Total" on the multiple workbook.

example:

files1.xlsx
files2.xlsx
files3.xlsx

files1.xlsx - the last row with text "Total" is at row 10.

files2.xlsx - the last row with text "Total" is at row 19.

files3.xlsx - the last row with text "Total" is at row 30.

(Note: the position of last row is not fix)

DestFile.xlsx - This file will be the destination file of the files1 to files3 that will be paste on sheet1 only.

So far I've this code below but the second files row overlaps with the the first file row.

```
Sub CombineFiles()

Dim bookList As Workbook Dim mergeObj, dirObj, filesObj, everyObj As Object Dim IRow, i As Long Dim ws As Worksheet Dim tag As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set dirObj = mergeObj.GetFolder("D:\CXT\") Set filesObj = dirObj.Files

For Each everyObj In filesObj

    Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)

    Set ws = bookList.Worksheets("10052018")
    IRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    For i = 1 To IRow
       tag = ws.Cells(i, 2)
       If tag = "*" Then
        IRow = i
        Exit For
       End If
    Next i

    IRow = IRow - 2

    Range("A3:L" & Range("B" & IRow).End(xlDown).Row).Copy

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
    Range("A" & IRow).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).PasteSpecial
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    bookList.Close
Next
End Sub
```

Hope somebody can help me.
Thanks in Advance,
Yeojz

Comment: Have you tried to do this? How familiar are you with Excel-Vba?

Comment: There are plenty of solutions on this site that show you how to do this. At the very least, the solutions can provide you with a starting point. This is not a code writing service, please put in the expected effort and then come back here with a specific question and people will be glad to help out :)